# leetcode implemente strstr C++ return pointers

Tags: c++

Implement strStr().

Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or null if needle is not part of haystack.

I wrote:

```
class Solution {
public:
    char *strStr(char *haystack, char *needle) {
    std::string s1(haystack);
    std::string s2(needle);

    if(s2.empty())
      {return haystack;}

    int a = s1.length();
    int b = s2.length();

    if(a < b)
      {return NULL;}

    for(int i = 0; i < a - b; i++)
      {
          int j = 0;
          int k = i;
          while(j < b && s2[j] == s1[k])
            {
                k++;
                j++;
            }
          if(j == b)
            {return (char*) s1[i];}
      }
      else return NULL;

    }
};
```

But Leetcode gives me the compiler error: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

....should I return some other stuff?.....

Comment: Can be simplified using `std::string::find`.. Seeing as you're using `std::string`.. Otherwise, get rid of it and use `strlen`.

Answer (score 3):

```
return (char*) s1[i];
```

There's two problems with that. First, you are converting the value if the character to a pointer.  You want to return the address of the character, not its value converted to a pointer. Second, `s1` is a local `std::string` initialized from the `haystack` parameter. You don't want to return a pointer to one of its characters, since it will be out of scope once the function returns. You want a pointer to a character in the original `haystack` c-string.

```
return &haystack[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine `string` as a sequence of chars, then `(char*) s1[i]` is really casting `char -> char *` in the code segment

```
if(j == b)
    {return (char*) s1[i];}
```

The  `operator[]` returns the i-th char of the string. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/  ,   [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5b%5d/))